# Jquery switch img src in another div doesn't work when followed by other functions

Tags: jquery

Edit: Solved. I had other `.click()` functions that followed the jQuery code for switching content that had to do with other classes. Would anyone be able to explain why or what I might of been doing wrong?

I know there have been a lot of questions related to replacing content, but my inexperience with jquery is driving me up the wall, and I have looked over many answered questions for days trying to figure out how to do this. I've included all of the jquery code I have for the function in case there's something about adding/removing classes that is messing up the code that is meant to switch out the content. Thank you so much for anyone who helps!

Goal: To switch src content of img of a main content div using a data-attribute when clicking a thumbnail img found in gallery.

Problem: My current jquery only works with the first `.gal-pg-open` class, and not the others (when they are clicked) in the gallery. So it is replacing the image, but only the `placeholder1.jpg -> large1.jpg`. When I try other images in the gallery it slides in an empty `.content` div.

jQuery

```
  $('.gal-pg-open').click(function() {

    // I start off with calling up css-transitions 
    //to slide the content div in

    $('.gal-pg').removeClass('gal-pg-moveToLeft');  
    $('.gal-pg').addClass('gal-pg-moveFromLeft'); 

    //Here I am hiding the gallery div that is 
    //behind the content div because otherwise I get height issues

    $('#gallery-grid').hide();

    var imglarge = $(this).find('img').data('imglarge');
    $('#lg-img').attr('src', imglarge);

});
$('.gal-pg-close').click(function() { 
     $('.gal-pg').addClass('gal-pg-moveToLeft');  
     $('#gallery-grid').show();  
});
```

HTML div where the content will be replaced.

```
    <div class="gal-pg">
                <nav>   
                </nav>

                <div class="content">
                    <figure>
                        <img id="lg-img" src="">
                    </figure>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Html for the gallery grid; `.gal-overlay` is a hover class that covers the image completely.

```
<div id="gallery-grid">
                <figure class="gal-pg-open gal-overlay">
                    <img src="placeholder1.jpg" data-imglarge="large1.jpg">
                        <figcaption> ...

                        </figcaption>       
                </figure>

                <figure class="gal-pg-open gal-overlay">
                    <img src="placeholder2.jpg" data-imglarge="large2.jpg"> 
                        <figcaption> ...

                        </figcaption>       
                </figure> 
      <!--Followed by many more images with same html structure-->
</div>
```

Comment: instead of data attribute try to change src of img

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle for this? And may be the complete code ?

Comment: Are you requesting the css or all of the html because its pretty big and a lot of the styling probably won't be helpful to look at, but I could try to slim it down to the basics as much as possible? I tried a fiddle a few hrs ago and wasn't able to replicate it for some reason, but I'll try again.

Comment: you can try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/m5wkyo92/

Comment: Thanks RRR, I gave it a go. Turned very messy, but it was interesting to see other jquery. I tried to get to work on my site, but the css-animation stopped working so div didn't slide in.